# Isekai manga where the mc wakes up as a ghost

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

Only had a few chapters and from what I remember the mc wakes up as a ghost then absorbs other ghosts and humans try to kill him so he kills them and absorbs their power

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. This is a bit terse on details at the moment, could you take a look at our [helpful story-id guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) and [edit] in anything you remember? For example: when did you read this? Did you read it online or in some other format? What happened to the MC that resulted in them waking up as a ghost?

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Meiou-sama ga Tooru no desu yo!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/meiou-sama-ga-tooru-no-desu-yo)

The story fits your description pretty well: the protagonist dies and returns to (un-)life as a spirit in a fantasy world. he has a "life absortion" ability, which he uses absorb the life force of goblins and other monsters, to become stronger. Most humans see him as an evil spirit and try to destroy him, but he defeats them and absorbs their life force (thus killing them).